# Attribute based styling in openlayers 6 cluster layer

Tags: style, clustering, openlayers

I was looking around for information, but i don't really understant the method. I wouldn't like to add more layers with the same name, because of the layerswitcher.
I would like to switch to attribute based styling at a resolution from cluster size based style. I didn't understant how to use the styleCache in this case. Maybe the answer is already in the code...
I'm getting back values at the attribute iteration but, i'm not setting the style.

```
            var styleCache = {};
            function getStyle(feature, resolution) {
                var size = feature.get("features").length;
                var style = styleCache[size];
                if (!style && resolution >= 21) {
                    var color =
                        size > 5
                            ? "192,0,0"
                            : size > 2
                            ? "255,128,0"
                            : "0,128,0";
                    var radius = Math.max(8, Math.min(size * 0.75, 20));
                    var dash = (2 * Math.PI * radius) / 6;
                    var dash = [0, dash, dash, dash, dash, dash, dash];
                    style = styleCache[size] = new Style({
                        image: new Circle({
                            radius: radius,
                            stroke: new Stroke({
                                color: "rgba(" + color + ",0.5)",
                                width: 15,
                                lineDash: dash,
                                lineCap: "butt"
                            }),
                            fill: new Fill({
                                color: "rgba(" + color + ",1)"
                            })
                        }),
                        text: new Text({
                            text: size.toString(),
                            //font: 'bold 12px comic sans ms',
                            //textBaseline: 'top',
                            fill: new Fill({
                                color: "#fff"
                            })
                        })
                    });
                }

                if (resolution <= 21) {
                    console.log(resolution);
                    const operable = new Style({
                        image: new Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 0],
                            anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                            src: "/images/map/e_1.png"
                        })
                    });
                    const nonFunctioning = new Style({
                        image: new Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 0],
                            anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                            src: "/images/map/e_0.png"
                        })
                    });
                    const underMaintance = new Style({
                        image: new Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 0],
                            anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                            src: "/images/map/e_2.png"
                        })
                    });

                    feature.get("features").forEach(function(feature) {
                        var status = feature.get("status_code");
                        if (status == 0) {
                            console.log(status) //working
                            style = nonFunctioning;
                        }
                        if (status == 1) {
                            style = operable;
                        }
                        if (status == 2) {
                            style = underMaintance;
                        }
                    });
                }
                return style;
            }
```

Comment: Two unnamed layers switched by minResolution and maxResolution will work inside a named LayerGroup with a layer switcher

Comment: I tried it now, But its only grays out the not visible layer. And I need to add a title property to manage the layer. But thanks, it's a useful information.

Comment: If you specify `combine: true,` in the layer group options it should appear as a single layer to the layer switcher